# PHP & MYSQL ambigious

Tags: php, mysql

This is the query i am using, but if i try to run it, it says : #1052 - Column 'loon_id' in where clause is ambiguous. I have spend some time searching now, but i have no idea what i am doing wrong.

Thanks in forehand

```
SELECT loonadministratie_algemeen.loon_id      AS algemeen_loon_id, 
       loonadministratie_algemeen.naam_werkgever, 
       loonadministratie_algemeen.bsn, 
       loonadministratie_algemeen.voorletters_achternaam, 
       loonadministratie_algemeen.geslacht, 
       loonadministratie_algemeen.meisjesnaam, 
       loonadministratie_algemeen.adres, 
       loonadministratie_algemeen.postcode_woonplaats, 
       loonadministratie_algemeen.geboortedatum, 
       loonadministratie_algemeen.nationaliteit, 
       loonadministratie_algemeen.burgelijke_staat_check, 
       loonadministratie_algemeen.burgelijke_staat, 
       loonadministratie_algemeen.telefoonnummer, 
       loonadministratie_algemeen.email, 
       loonadministratie_algemeen.bang_gironummer, 
       loonadministratie_algemeen.loonheffingskorting_toepassen, 
       loonadministratie_algemeen.identiteitsbewijs, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.loon_id AS dienstverband_loon_id, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.datum_in_dienst, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.beroep_functie, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.werknemer_werkeloos_check, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.werknemer_werkeloos_uitkering, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.arbeidsgehandycapte_status_check, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.gehandycapte_status_input, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.leerling_stagiaire_check, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.leerling_stagiaire_wat, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.arbeidpatroon_ma, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.arbeidpatroon_di, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.arbeidpatroon_wo, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.arbeidpatroon_do, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.arbeidpatroon_vr, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.arbeidspatroon_za, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.arbeidpatroon_zo, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.urentoeslag, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.diploma_bhv_check, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.diploma_bhv_input, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.soort_contract_check, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.soort_contract_tm, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.loonschaal, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.brutoloon, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.bruto_loon_per, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.uurloon_check, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.vaste_onkosten_check, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.vaste_onkosten_input, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.onderbouwing_vaste_onkosten, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.vergoeding_woon_werk_check, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.vergoeding_woon_werk_input, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.enkele_reis_woon_werk, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.aantal_reizen_per_week, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.auto_van_werkgever, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.cataloguswaarde, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.kenteken_auto, 
       loonadministratie_dienstverband.eigen_bijdrage_privegebruik, 
       loonadministratie_aanvullingen.loon_id  AS aanvulling_loon_id, 
       loonadministratie_aanvullingen.aanvullingen 
FROM   loonadministratie_algemeen 
       INNER JOIN loonadministratie_dienstverband 
               ON algemeen_loon_id = dienstverband_loon_id 
       INNER JOIN loonadministratie_aanvullingen 
               ON algemeen_loon_id = aanvulling_loon_id 
WHERE  loon_id = 1
```

Comment: You need to specify the table name too when using JOIN such as: `LEFT JOIN table_name.column_name ON...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juste add `loonadministratie_algemeen.loon_id or loonadministratie_aanvullingen.loon_id`
 to where, you couldn't use loon_id alone

try with this :

```
SELECT
loonadministratie_algemeen.loon_id as algemeen_loon_id, 
loonadministratie_algemeen.naam_werkgever, 
loonadministratie_algemeen.bsn, 
loonadministratie_algemeen.voorletters_achternaam, 
loonadministratie_algemeen.geslacht, 
loonadministratie_algemeen.meisjesnaam, 
loonadministratie_algemeen.adres, 
loonadministratie_algemeen.postcode_woonplaats, 
loonadministratie_algemeen.geboortedatum, 
loonadministratie_algemeen.nationaliteit, 
loonadministratie_algemeen.burgelijke_staat_check, 
loonadministratie_algemeen.burgelijke_staat, 
loonadministratie_algemeen.telefoonnummer, 
loonadministratie_algemeen.email, 
loonadministratie_algemeen.bang_gironummer, 
loonadministratie_algemeen.loonheffingskorting_toepassen, 
loonadministratie_algemeen.identiteitsbewijs,

loonadministratie_dienstverband.loon_id as dienstverband_loon_id, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.datum_in_dienst, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.beroep_functie, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.werknemer_werkeloos_check, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.werknemer_werkeloos_uitkering, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.arbeidsgehandycapte_status_check, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.gehandycapte_status_input, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.leerling_stagiaire_check, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.leerling_stagiaire_wat, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.arbeidpatroon_ma, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.arbeidpatroon_di, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.arbeidpatroon_wo, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.arbeidpatroon_do, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.arbeidpatroon_vr, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.arbeidspatroon_za, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.arbeidpatroon_zo, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.urentoeslag, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.diploma_bhv_check, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.diploma_bhv_input, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.soort_contract_check, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.soort_contract_tm, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.loonschaal, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.brutoloon, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.bruto_loon_per, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.uurloon_check, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.vaste_onkosten_check, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.vaste_onkosten_input, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.onderbouwing_vaste_onkosten, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.vergoeding_woon_werk_check, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.vergoeding_woon_werk_input, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.enkele_reis_woon_werk, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.aantal_reizen_per_week, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.auto_van_werkgever, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.cataloguswaarde, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.kenteken_auto, 
loonadministratie_dienstverband.eigen_bijdrage_privegebruik,
loonadministratie_aanvullingen.loon_id as aanvulling_loon_id, 
loonadministratie_aanvullingen.aanvullingen 
FROM loonadministratie_algemeen
INNER JOIN loonadministratie_dienstverband 
ON algemeen_loon_id = dienstverband_loon_id 
INNER JOIN loonadministratie_aanvullingen 
ON algemeen_loon_id = aanvulling_loon_id 
where loonadministratie_algemeen.loon_id=1
```